# Minute as a time unit for scheduled reminders

Tags: scheduled-reminders, civirules, core

Right now the smallest unit is the hour, so I can schedule a reminder 1 hour before or after something.

What do I do if I wanted to send a reminder 30 minutes before something? Is this possible right now?

If not, how difficult would it be to make an extension that would introduce **minute** as a time unit for reminders? Would this be difficult to achieve? Are there any clever workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Minutes as a scheduled reminder unit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/21893) is available in CiviCRM 5.44+.

Answer (score 0):

It's a legitimate question although even if you could do it per minute, you'd then have to have cron run every minute, which is technically possible but might be a bit excessive.

If you're talking about reminders for activity assignees, an alternative might be to turn on the setting at Administer - Customize - Display Prefs - Include ICal Invite to Activity Assignees. Then they can put it in their calendar and they can set it to remind them as desired.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about triggering cron like every 5, 10 or 15 min. Which shouldn't be a problem. Even if I could enter a fraction of the hour e.g. 0.25 would do the job, but right now it can only receive an integer. I need this for a variety of functionalities, but what prompted me to write this questions is the Events reminders use cases. This is relevant now during the pandemic, as there are many online events and sending the reminders 15 minutes before the webinar would be optimal (1 hour time resolution isn't fine enough)

Comment: you can run scheduled tasks at specific time (with minutes) using https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/cronplus extension